# Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse ADT 22. I didn't get that lame errors with other projects until I exported this project. I included 2 more jar library files into the project's lib directory and then it was not going to run... The CPU USAGE got 100% limit and the Eclipse turned into "unresponsive"..
The error messages:

```
[Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
[OsmAnd]     Conversion to Dalvik format failed: 
             Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I have been trying a lot of ideas in here for one day.... and it's still not working I am so frustrated now. 
This is what I had in my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

When I unchecked the Android Private Library It run but in the emulator it stopped unexpectedly

Please help me out of this issue. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is the error you are getting in emulator ? please share logs if possible.

Comment: Sorry this is like a mess but... when I unchecked the Android private library and run... it showed this error

Comment: 03-23 22:00:00.573: E/Trace(627): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-23 22:00:00.783: E/dalvikvm(627): Could not find class 'com.aspose.pdf.Document', referenced from method com.aspose.pdf.android.example.extracttext.MainActivity.ExtractText
03-23 22:00:00.783: W/dalvikvm(627): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8 (Lcom/aspose/pdf/Document;) in Lcom/aspose/pdf/android/example/extracttext/MainActivity;
03-23 22:00:00.783: D/dalvikvm(627): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0036
03-2303: D/dalvikvm(627): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call

Comment: 03-23 22:00:00.973: D/AndroidRuntime(627): Shutting down VM
03-23 22:00:00.984: W/dalvikvm(627): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
03-23 22:00:00.993: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 22:00:00.993: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aspose.pdf.Document
03-23 22:00:00.993: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.aspose.pdf.android.example.extracttext.MainActivity.ExtractText(MainActivity.java:16)
03-23 22:00:00.993: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.aspose.pdf.android.example.extracttext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42

Comment: When I checked the Android private library I didn't even start... it went unresponsive

Comment: Looks like you are hitting method count of grater than 65K with libs included, and if you remove lib then android is not able to find class defs.
Try only checking/unchecking jars in android private lib. Means only adding limited jars.

Comment: There are 3 jar files in Android private library:
Aspose.Pdf.Android-1.5-javadoc.jar (required)
Aspose.Pdf.Adnroid-1.5.jar (require)
android-support-v4.jar

Comment: and it seems only delete jar files in the project's libs directory will remove what under Android private library (which is impossible because these libraries are required)

Comment: This project runs perfectly in another computer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are facing the same problem. I finally found the solution by simply moving the project to my default workspace folder... This is odd but solved my problem anyway